# Wrapping comment text beneath a username in an Android app

Tags: java, android, user-interface, parse-platform

[I've sufficed to put the user comment below the username for now, because otherwise the comment appears in a block directly to the right of the username and looks very awkward.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBnpk.jpg)

[You'll see on this Instagram example, the beginning of the comment begins right after the username but then wraps to beneath the username on all subsequent lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWIDH.jpg)

My problem is that when I inject a user comment in my feed to the right of a username, the entire comment block appears to the right. It looks chunky and awkward. I would like to achieve an effect similar to Instagram wherein the first line appears directly after the username and where the second and all subsequent lines wrap beneath it. I was wondering if there were any common XML tricks to wrap the second and all subsequent lines of my comment String beneath the username String, as is done on Instagram.

My second thought would be to programmatically break up the lines in the comment object and append several short strings together to form a single, cohesive comment block.

Any experienced UI developers out there know of any tricks? How can I account for the length of the username? I suppose just indenting the first line, however that is done, would only work if you assumed everyone had the same username length, which is obviously not a good assumption. If not, has anyone achieved an effect like this using a backend? And if so, what would be a good first direction to get started on something like that?

**The XML:**

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/comment1Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

       <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/comment1Layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/commentUser1"
        tools:text="commentUsername"
        android:textColor="#44d7a8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/commentText1"
        tools:text="This is a comment."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</Linear Layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Link inside comment]

Try using just one TextView:

```
user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.commentUser1);
user.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.commentUserName)));
user.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and define the string as:
    `<string name="commentUserName"><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.google.com">commentUsername</a>]]> Los
        textos simulados son aquellos textos que, en ausencia 
        de un texto definitivo, sirven como sustituto de futuros contenidos en
        la producción de maquetas para publicaciones o sitios
        web. También son llamados textos dummy, ficticios o de relleno.</string>`

Comment: Excuse the size of the picture

Comment: Can you take a look at my second updated answer above? I can't use HTML or XML because the string is being loaded from my server. Is there any way to directly modify the style of the first portion of my newly concatenated string? This is the line of interest: new Object[]{commentUser1.getText().toString(). For example, can I make this portion of the string bold and green, or better yet, invisible?

Answer (score 0):

So I did some research and used SpannableString to set the LeadingMarginSpan to a length in "dp" that is just slightly greater than the length of the username! Great. It works. Well, it's a good start. It works for one unique username length.

Now I've got to dynamically set the length of LeadingMarginSpan based on the length of the username string.

```
public void setCommentText1(String text) {
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(text);
    s.setSpan(new android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(150, 0), 0, s.length(), 0);
    commentText1.setText(s);
}
```

Anyway, I hope this helps somebody else!

**Update 1:**

I had the string for the username stored so I just got its length and then put that value multiplied by a factor I called "usernameSpan" (set to "150" above).

```
public void setCommentText1(String text) {
    int usernameLength = username.length();
    int usernameSpan = 35;
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(text);
    s.setSpan(new android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(usernameLength*usernameSpan, 0), 0, s.length(), 0);
    commentText1.setText(s);
}
```

This is still not the best answer. Ideally I'd get the maximum Ems of the string and multiply that by the username so that the LeadingMarginSpan is equal to the username + a little space to allow for the beginning of the comment. I've tried username.getMaxEms() but that doesn't seem to work because the username string is set dynamically so I don't know if it actually knows the max Ems of the entire string after the string has been populated. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it! Thanks.

**Why not concatenate?**

A reason they shouldn't just be concatenated is that username TextView has some programmatic elements to it, such as linking to a profile. So the optimal solution would have to look like something from above.

**Update 2:**

```
public void setCommentText1(String text) {
    commentText1.setText(String.format("%s %s", new Object[]{commentUser1.getText().toString(), text}));
}
```

I've removed the leadingMarginSpan (finding the width of the text view seems to be very unreliable) and opted to place the username and comments Strings directly on top of one another. The comments String contains the username, pulled from our server, so that the spacing matches up for each unique comment. If I can somehow make the user portion of this combined string invisible then we have ourselves a working, albeit slightly messy, solution.

**Final Working Solution:**

For my particular problem I needed to use a SpannableStringBuilder to style the first portion of the concat String (this ended up being commentUsername1Spannable) to match the color of my original username TextView and then leave the second portion (text, or Comment string) without formatting. It works!

```
public void setCommentUser1(String text) {
    commentUser1.setText(text);
}

public void setCommentText1(String text) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    String commentUsername1 = commentUser1.getText().toString();
    SpannableString commentUsername1Spannable = new SpannableString(commentUsername1);
    commentUsername1Spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb()), 0, commentUsername1Spannable.length(), 0);
    builder.append(commentUsername1Spannable);
    builder.append(" ");
    builder.append(text);
    commentText1.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```