# Styling only part of a concatenated string (Android)

Tags: java, android, string, user-interface

I realize the following code is incorrect, so treat it as psuedo-code I suppose.

```
public void setCommentText1(String text) {
    String commentUsername1 = commentUser1.getText().toString();
    commentUsername1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
    commentText1.setText(String.format("%s %s", new Object[]{commentUsername1, text}));
}
```

Why can't I do something like this? I have a formatted String that takes a String from my Username object and a string from my Comment object. I want to set the Username to a specific color (ideally set to invisible), but I can't rely on injecting HTML or on XML because I'm pulling the Strings from my server. Why can't I set the color of just one of the components of the string? Sure, you can't setTextColor on a String (it's a TextView modifier), but is there an alternative?

See my original post here, which is related but is of a different question overall: [Wrapping comment text beneath a username in an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558245/wrapping-comment-text-beneath-a-username-in-an-android-app)

**Final Working Solution:**

The marked answer below is great, and works generally. It's also a lot cleaner, but for my particular problem I needed to do the following:

```
public void setCommentUser1(String text) {
    commentUser1.setText(text);
}

public void setCommentText1(String text) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    String commentUsername1 = commentUser1.getText().toString();
    SpannableString commentUsername1Spannable = new SpannableString(commentUsername1);
    commentUsername1Spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, commentUsername1Spannable.length(), 0);
    builder.append(commentUsername1Spannable);
    builder.append(" ");
    builder.append(text);
    commentText1.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you should use `Spannable`.

```
final SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(username)
        .append(" ")
        .append(text)
        .setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd")),
                0 /* startIndex */,
                username.length() /* endIndex */,
                Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE /* flags */);

commentText1.setText(builder);
```

Comment: Checking it out now. Thanks! Will get back to you asap.

Answer (score 1):

`SpannableStringBuilder` is the way you can achieve this.

```
public void setCommentText1(String text) {
    String user = "Johny says: ";
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(user + text);
    builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd")),
            0, user.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    this.text.setText(builder);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working code that you can use to highlight some part of string:

```
     private void highlightTextPart(TextView textView, int index, String regularExpression) {
        String fullText = textView.getText().toString();
        int startPos = 0;
        int endPos = fullText.length();
        String[] textParts = fullText.split(regularExpression);
        if (index < 0 || index > textParts.length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        if (textParts.length > 1) {
            startPos = fullText.indexOf(textParts[index]);
            endPos = fullText.indexOf(regularExpression, startPos);
            if (endPos == -1) {
                endPos = fullText.length();
            }
        }
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(fullText);
        ColorStateList blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][] { new int[] {}}, new int[] { Color.BLUE });
        TextAppearanceSpan textAppearanceSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC, -1, blueColor, null);
        BackgroundColorSpan backgroundColorSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
        spannable.setSpan(textAppearanceSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spannable.setSpan(backgroundColorSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(spannable);
    }
```

Then in your activity, call like the following:

```
    int index = 3;
    String regularExpression = " ";
    String text = "Hello StackOverflow From BNK!";
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if (textView != null) {
        textView.setText(text);
        highlightTextPart(textView, index, regularExpression);
    }
```

[image]